# How to redirect URL based on URL structure

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to redirect URL based on the URL structure. This is for a WordPress site.

For example, I have the following pages.

```
http://www.example.com/content/status/level-a/page-a
http://www.example.com/content/status/level-b/page-b
http://www.example.com/content/status/level-c/page-a
http://www.example.com/content/status/level-d/page-d
```

This structure must match.

Currently, the status has a $status = level-a;

So anything with a status that is not level-a will get redirected to the homepage. So far I have this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_based_on_status' );

  function redirect_based_on_status() {

  if (  $status == "level-a"; && (first == "content" && second == "status" the-third-subodmain != $status ) {

 wp_redirect(site_url()); 
    exit;
}
}
```

This is something along the lines of what I'm going for, but I don't know how to do it. If JavaScript or jQuery is an option, I am all ears!

Comment: May be this approach could help, please scroll to “ Add rewrite tags” section https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress/